# Setting up culture in WCF based on claim

Tags: wcf, globalization, wif

I have a custom claim that determines language user will be using.

I have extension to ClaimsPrincipal, that checks for that claim and generates appropriate culture:

```
    public static CultureInfo Culture(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        Claim claim = principal.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.Language);
        if (claim == null)
            return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
        else
            return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(claim.Value);
    }
```

I've also implemented custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler and custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager and both work fine. Actually entire solution works just fine, except for the fact that I'm unable to find appropriate point in WCF pipeline where I can set Thread.CurrentCulture based on the extension above.

I've tried ICallContextInitializer, IDispatchMessageInspector, but none of the above can actually see my ClaimsPrincipal (it gets overriden with empty principal). However, in my service operations, ClaimsPrincipal.Current points properly to identity I've created in UserNameSecurityTokenHandler.

Where should I set this Claim-dependant culture?

Answer (score 0):

For WCF data service i use ProcessingRequest event:

```
public class ConfigurationManagementDataService : SecurityDataService<ConfigurationContext>
{
public ConfigurationManagementDataService()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ConfigurationContext>(null);
        ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += OnProcessingRequest;
    }
public void OnProcessingRequest(object sender, DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs dataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs)
    {
    //assign IPrincipal to a Thread.Principal
    //we must set both, but Thread.CurrentPrincipal is a main
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.User = principal;
        }

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```